# I ":so %"-d a vimball file, but opening vim gives a wall of errors [SOLVED - Lack of attention]

Tags: vim

I wanted syntax highlighting for Haskell. What I did:

- I downloaded a `.vba` file from https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/. It was https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/vimfiles/haskellmode-20101118.vba to be exact.
- I opened the file in vim and ran `:so %`. It finished without any errors. I quit the editor.
- I opened a file with vim with the `.hs` (Haskell code) extension, and got this wall of errors:

```
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Autocommands for "*.hs"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>12_LoadFTPlugin[17]..script /home/floff/.vim/
ftplugin/haskell_doc.vim:
line   66:
haskell_doc.vim WARNING: please set g:haddock_browser!
line   69:
E117: Unknown function: haskellmode#GHC
line   72:
E121: Undefined variable: g:ghc
E116: Invalid arguments for function substitute(g:ghc,'\(.*\)ghc','\1ghc-pkg','')
line   77:
E121: Undefined variable: g:ghc_pkg
E116: Invalid arguments for function executable(g:ghc_pkg)
line   99:
E121: Undefined variable: g:ghc
E116: Invalid arguments for function system(g:ghc . ' --print-libdir'),'\n','','')
E116: Invalid arguments for function substitute(system(g:ghc . ' --print-libdir'),'\n','','')
line  118:
E121: Undefined variable: s:docdir
line  119:
E121: Undefined variable: s:docdir
line  123:
E121: Undefined variable: s:libraries
E116: Invalid arguments for function filewritable(s:libraries)
line  131:
E121: Undefined variable: s:haddock_indexfiledir
line  263:
E121: Undefined variable: s:guide
line  264:
E121: Undefined variable: s:flagref
E116: Invalid arguments for function filereadable(s:flagref)
```

Needless to say, the plugin isn't doing any syntax highlighting. I have no idea what the problem is. If someone could  provide some insight, I would be very grateful.

Comment: On the site you link to, there's a section called "Setup" which explains which variables to set etc. Did you follow those instructions? It might be worth a try.

Comment: I missed that. I'll take a look, thank you.

Comment: If that changes anything, feel free to [edit] your question or ask a new one.